# Convert birth date to age with localized years label using swift on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, date, localization

Is there any good library that can display birth date in format like: 1 year or 5 years (And more complicated staff for other languages)?

`NSDateForamatte`r can do a lot, but not this. Also there is https://github.com/MatthewYork/DateTools but it displays things wrong in some languages, and also adds this weird and unnecessary "ago" thing.

Comment: Use `DateComponentsFormatter`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method is to use `DateComponentsFormatter`. An example (Swift 3):

```
let birthDate = ... // The birthdate
let dcf = DateComponentsFormatter()
dcf.allowedUnits = .year
dcf.unitsStyle = .full
let age = dcf.string(from: birthDate, to: Date())
print(age)
```

You can adjust the properties of the formatter to get the exact output you wish.

Comment: I tried this`let birthDate = NSDate() // The birthdate
let dcf = DateComponentsFormatter()
dcf.calendar = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.chinese)
dcf.allowedUnits = .year
dcf.unitsStyle = .full
let age = dcf.string(from: birthDate as Date, to: Date())
print(age)` but not print Chinese year.

Comment: If you are not in a Chinese locale then you also need to set the formatter's `locale` appropriately.

Comment: Thanks! Learn a lot from you!

Comment: Normally you don't want to set either the calendar or the locale. You want the formatter to use the user's current locale so the user sees the age formatted for their locale.